# How to use Corcel with Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have developed a `web service` with `Laravel` framework and a `wordpress` database by `jgrossi/corcel` and it worked fine on a host. Since I have moved my web service from the host to a `CentOS` server, the web service functions return an empty JSON and I can not understand the reason. Of course I have changed the database config but is there any configuration that must be changed?

Comment: Did you read the logs?

Comment: Do you mean PHP error log?There is no error there.

Comment: Your logs in Laravel.

Comment: local.ERROR: could not find driver {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver at /var/www/html/test/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver at /var/www/html/test/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)

Comment: There's your problem, google the error, I'm sure you'll make it work buddy.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. pdo_mysql module was not properly installed on the server and it caused database connection errors.

Comment: I'm glad. Happy new year.